# How do I differentiate $\sin(x)^{\cos(x^3)}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponentiation

I'm taking a calc 1 class and I have come across a function that I'm having difficulty finding answers on the web.

$y=\sin(x)^{\cos(x^3)}$

I know there's some chain rule to apply, but what do I do with the cos(x)?

I am assuming this:

$y' = \cos(x^3).(\sin(x)')^{\cos(x^3) - 1}$

Is my thinking correct?

Comment: Is that exponent on the argument $\;x\;$ or  it applies on the whole of $\;\sin x\;$ ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, added the changes

Comment: @amateurjustin Note that the rule $y=(f(x))^a \implies y'=a(f(x))^{a-1}$ only holds for $a$ real and fixed. It seems you are trying to apply something similar to this. For $y=(h(x))^{g(x)}$ the standard trick is use that (for $h(x)>0$) $y=e^{g(x) \log(h(x)}$ and then use the derivation rule for $y=e^{f(x)}$.

Answer (score 4):

Use that

$$y=e^{\cos (x^3)\log(\sin x)}$$

and by chain rule we have

$$y=e^{f(x)}\implies y'=f'(x)e^{f(x)}$$

Comment: Thanks so much! I've been looking all over the web and was not able to find this answer!

Comment: @amateurjustin Often when we face with functions in the form $(f(x))^{g(x)}$ this manipulation helps a lot. You are welcome! Bye

Comment: What is this method called?

Comment: It is [logarithmic differentiation](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LogDiff.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is with a differential rule rarely taught: the differential of $q^m$ (I'm using these instead of $u$ and $v$ because the font makes $v$ look too much like $u$).  Then you don't have to do any weird manipulations.  The rule is:
$$
d(q^m) = mq^{m - 1}\,dq + \ln(q)q^m\,dm
$$

Note that this is just a combination of the power rule and the exponential rule.

So, plugging in your values, that would be:
$$q = \sin(x) \\ dq = \cos(x)\,dx$$ and $$m = \cos(x^3) \\ dm = -\sin(x^3) 3x^2\,dx$$
Plugging those into the formula gives:
$$
\cos(x^3)\sin(x)^{\cos(x^3) - 1} \cos(x)\,dx + \ln(\sin(x))\sin(x)^{\cos(x^3)}(-\sin(x^3) 3x^2)\, dx$$
Therefore:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \cos(x^3)\sin(x)^{\cos(x^3) - 1} \cos(x) + \ln(\sin(x))\sin(x)^{\cos(x^3)} (-\sin(x^3) 3x^2) $$

It's still ugly, but the nice thing about using the rule is that there's no manipulation - you can basically just apply rules mechanistically (I hope I did all that right - it is sometimes difficult to type in a bunch of different terms and keep them all straight).